# Python modules inherit imports

Tags: python

How can I use a module that was imported in the main module in other module that was imported as well?

Example: In the example below the module_2 should use the "time" module imported in module_1.

**module_1**

```
import time
import module_2
text = 'Hello Word'
seconds = 2
modulo_2.print_time(text, seconds)
```

**module_2**

```
def print_time(text, seconds):
    print(text)
    time.sleep(seconds)
    print(text + ' again')
```

Comment: You can't - not without some very hacky workaround that manually modify your module namespaces. The solution is to `import time` in module 2, not in module 1.

Comment: What if `module_2` is called from a module that doesn't import `time`? A module should import everything it needs.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for helping! In fact, this is just a example... what I am really working is one main module that import pandas and there is a loot of functions from other modules that also using pandas, so I do not want to import pandas in those other modules...I had thought in pass the module as a parameter, but since I am new in python, just want to know with there ir any other way... Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard is import all modules used in the file, ie import time in module_2.

But if you are an anarchist, you could send a module through the parameter to the function, like this:

**module_2**

```
def print_time(text, seconds, time_module):
    print(text)
    time_module.sleep(seconds)
    print(text + ' again')
```

**module_1**

```
import time
import module_2
text = 'Hello Word'
seconds = 2
modulo_2.print_time(text, seconds, time)
```

Comment: Hi Cristian! Thank you for helping!
In fact, this is just a example... what I am really working is one main module that import pandas and there is a loot of functions from other modules that also using pandas, so I do not want to import pandas in those other modules... I had thought in pass the module as a parameter, but since I am new in python, just want to know with there ir any other way...
PS: funny the anarchist part.

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies of a function or class defined in a python module or package should be closed/meet in that package or module, it is useless and unclean to do this way